# Is there a open-search solution for python?

Tags: python, search, lucene

lucene-like would be preferred.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why you need lucene-like when you can use lucene (PyLucene) :)

http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/

It is great and builds against the latest build of lucene

quote from site:

> PyLucene is a Python extension for
>   accessing Java Lucene. Its goal is to
>   allow you to use Lucene's text
>   indexing and searching capabilities
>   from Python. It is API compatible with
>   the latest version of Java Lucene,
>   version 2.9.0 as of October 13th,
>   2009.
>
> PyLucene is not a Lucene port but a
>   Python wrapper around Java Lucene.
>   PyLucene embeds a Java VM with Lucene
>   into a Python process. The PyLucene
>   Python extension, a Python module
>   called lucene, is machine-generated by
>   JCC.
>
> PyLucene is built with JCC, a C++ code
>   generator that makes it possible to
>   call into Java classes from Python via
>   Java's Native Invocation Interface
>   (JNI). Sources for JCC are included
>   with the PyLucene sources.

Comment: thanks for the reply.


"PyLucene is not a Lucene port but a Python wrapper around Java Lucene. PyLucene embeds a Java VM with Lucene into a Python process."

May there be some performance problems?

I' ll try it.

Comment: I have used it and there aren't performance problems, but that depends on what you expect, we were able to index 1000 docs per sec easily

Answer (score 12):

You can also check [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.com), it has native JSON interface so integrating with it in python should be simpler. Seems like [Simon Willison](http://simonwillison.net/2010/Feb/11/elastic/) thinks it got potential...

Comment: I looked at solr and pylucene. ElasticSearch looks like the only option I have to work with lucene and python, with an easy setup and without embellishments. Unluckily whoosh is not an option for me as I need some features which are currently supported only by lucene.

Answer (score 3):

See **[SolPython](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolPython)** and **[solrpy](http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/)**

> ### What is solrpy?
>
> solrpy is a python client for solr, an
>   enterprise search server built on top
>   of lucene. solrpy allows you to add
>   documents to a solr instance, and then
>   to perform queries and gather search
>   results from solr using your favorite
>   programming language--python.

Answer (score 1):

How about [python bindings for Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/)?

Answer (score 0):

How about Sphinx? http://www.sphinxsearch.com/

It has Python bindings included.
I don't have comparision with other solutions like Lucene, 
but I'm using Sphinx for CRM and it works very well, 
indexing emails, notes etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Xapian](http://xapian.org/) is an excellent Lucene-alternative, with fairly good Python-bindings, which is also easier to install than pylucene.